# Importing C.scintilla_new() in Cgo package

Tags: go, cgo, scintilla

```
package main

//#cgo CFLAGS: -I/home/me/geany/scintilla/include
//#include <ScintillaWidget.h>
import "C"

import (
    "github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk"
)

func main() {
    gtk.Init(nil)
    window := gtk.NewWindow(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    window.SetPosition(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
    window.SetTitle("GTK Go!")
    window.SetIconName("textview")
    window.Connect("destroy", gtk.MainQuit)
    window.SetSizeRequest(600, 600)
    C.scintilla_new();
    window.ShowAll()
    gtk.Main()
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
# _/home/me/gosci/gosci
could not determine kind of name for C.scintilla_new
```

The definition is obviously in the header at line 58:

```
GtkWidget*  scintilla_new       (void);
```

How to compile this?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly `GtkWidget` is not declared in `ScintillaWidget.h` and you need to `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` first.